# SQL JOIN query failing

Tags: php, debugging, join

I've looked up and down here but couldn't find anything that works.  I'm trying to join two tables and output team1id and team2id from the resulting table.

```
//Query
$sql = "SELECT match.*, matchrelations.match_id, matchrelations.poolname
        FROM match JOIN matchrelations
        ON match.id=matchrelations.match_id
        WHERE matchrelations.poolname='$poolname'";

//Debugging
if (!$check1_res) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
}
//Query database
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

//Echo
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
  $team1 = $row['match.team1id'];
  $team2 = $row['match.team2id'];
  echo "$team1 VS $team2";
  echo "<br>";
}
```

The error is being thrown in the sql statement, and produces error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, matchrelations.match_id, matchrelations.poolname FROM match JOIN matchrela' at line 1

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like match is a reserved word in mysql.  Try this:

```
SELECT `match`.*, matchrelations.match_id, matchrelations.poolname
        FROM `match` JOIN matchrelations
        ON `match`.id=matchrelations.match_id
        WHERE matchrelations.poolname='$poolname';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql = "SELECT m.*, mr.match_id, mr.poolname
        FROM `match` m JOIN `matchrelations` mr
        ON (m.id=mr.match_id)
        WHERE mr.poolname='$poolname'";
```

Comment: That worked!  Can you explain what was wrong with my code and why this worked though?

Comment: Hi, first of all, you have to check for every query you make, what are the reserved words, for example: "match", "option", "order". In your case "FROM match JOIN..." have an error because match is a reserved word, but if you put a back quote in that word your are telling to mySql that match is a table, and its better to put back quotes for every table. Then you put an alias for the table, for example `match` m .  that way mySql always going to know that "m" is the match table.